# App só traz um registro no Android

Tags: java, android

Estou desenvolvendo um app no Android onde os dados estão em um web-based desenvolvido em PHP/Mysql. O código que estou usando para pegar os dados é:

```
public class ListarDados extends AppCompatActivity {

public static TextView data;

//String url = ""; //

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listar_dados);

        data = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fetchedata);

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if(networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()){

           new SolicitaDados().execute();

        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nenhuma conexão ativa", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    private class SolicitaDados extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        String data = "";
        String dataParsed = "";
        String singleParsed = "";

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids){
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://192.168.0.13/plataforma/android/listar.php");
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String linhas = "";

                while(linhas != null){
                    linhas = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    data = data + linhas;
                }

                JSONArray JA = new JSONArray(data);

                  for(int i = 0; i < JA.length(); i++){
                      JSONObject JO = (JSONObject) JA.get(i);
                      singleParsed = "Email:" + JO.get("Email") + "Senha:" + JO.get("Senha") + "\n";
                      dataParsed = dataParsed + singleParsed + "\n";
                  }

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            ListarDados.data.setText(this.dataParsed);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Intent voltar = new Intent(ListarDados.this, ConteudoSistema.class);
        startActivity(voltar);
    }
}
```

Apesar no banco de dados ter 04 registros:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o PHP estar dessa forma:

```
<?php
$conexao = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','sucesso','projetos');

$sql = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * FROM pe_mobile");

$mostrar = array();
//$mostrar["dados"] = array();

foreach($sql as $linha){

$listar["Email"] = $linha["Email"];
$listar["Senha"] = $linha["Senha"];

array_push($mostrar,$listar);
}
echo json_encode($mostrar);
```

Tenho como resultado:

```
[{"Email":"fernando@pessoa.com","Senha":"123"},{"Email":"rui@barbosa.com","Senha":"321"},{"Email":"carlos@drummond.com","Senha":"456"},{"Email":"cecilia@meireles.com","Senha":"654"}]
```

Porém quando executo o app, ele só me retorna o primeiro registro. Como faço para trazer todos os registros?

No dbugue do ArrayJSON, retorna o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Fala Fox. Então talvez ja deve ter feito isso, mas ja tentou debugar e inspecionar o ArrayJSON JA?

Comment: Olá Marlon. Ainda não tentei fazer isso. Para eu poder debugar, seria dentro do próprio Android Studio? Pergunto, pois estou começando agora a trabalhar com essa IDE e não tenho muita experiência nele.

Comment: Sim, é so na hora de buildar vc escolher o botão do icone de bug, dai colocar um break point na linha da variável e testa novamente a operação. Quando passar pela linha a IDE vai congelar o processamento e você vai conseguir inspecionar o que há dentro da variavel

Comment: Certo. Debuguei e coloquei o print no post. Parece que ele está retornando corretamente os valores.

Answer (score -1):

Não tenho certeza e não tenho como confirmar no momento, mas se não me engano você pode usar `mysqli_fetch_all()`, que já vai retornar todos os registros desejados em um array, para que você possa enviar diretamente como JSON para a resposta da requisição.

A ideia seria essa:

```
<?php
$conexao = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','sucesso','projetos');
$sql = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * FROM pe_mobile");
echo json_encode( mysqli_fetch_all( $sql, \MYSQLI_ASSOC ) );
```

Seria interessante você definir o cabeçalho da resposta para JSON também:

```
header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );//antes do echo
```

E para desenvolvimento seria interessante habilitar mensagens de erros:

```
error_reporting( E_ALL );//primeira linha de código após abertura do <?php
```

Veja esses exemplos do manual também: https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php

Comment: Olá Erick. Tentei dessa forma, mas ele também só retorna o primeiro registro. Acredito que o problema esteja no Java, pois quando dou um print diretamente na tela, o PHP traz todos os resultados.